# google near by places api not returning any resluts with key word birthday venue near me and type court_hall

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, search

I am searching with "birthday venue near me" keyword in google maps there are many suggestions but through google api I am not getting any data. Please some one help me out to get data for any kind of key words like "birthday venue near me", "coffee shops" etc.

Below is the API I am using

[google API to get near by birthday venues](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4474,78.3762&radius=5000&type=court_hall&keyword=b%27day%20venues%20near%20me&key=yourKey)

Comment: your API is working fine 

please try this :- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.4474,78.3762&radius=5000&type=court_hall&keyword=school&key=AIzaSyCkFfFiYlBfx32BRYDP_oFw_6lEt3cApcA

Comment: you should simply enter keyword "birthday" or "food" or "hotel" or "school" etc what ever you want

Comment: @SandipGill  happy for your response but I am looking for is there any way to get google data if I search like any custom key words

Comment: Yes its working here but you can not use special characters like "b'day" because your key word is requested with url and api type is GET so you should avoid it

Answer (score 0):

We can use textsearch api instead of nearbysearch

[This API will work](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=birthday%20venues%20near%20me&location=17.4474,78.3762&radius=10000&key=YourKey)